# Error with Python dictionary: str object has no attribute append

Tags: python

I am writing code in python.
My input line is "all/DT remaining/VBG all/NNS of/IN "

I want to create a dictionary with one key and multiple values
For example - all:[DT,NNS]

```
groupPairsByKey={}
Code:
for line in fileIn:
    lineLength=len(line)
    words=line[0:lineLength-1].split(' ')
    for word in words:
        wordPair=word.split('/')
                  if wordPair[0] in groupPairsByKey:
                    groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]].append(wordPair[1])
<getting error here>
                  else:
                    groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]] = [wordPair[1]]
```

Comment: Can you share the error you get?

Comment: Is `groupPairsByKey` an empty dictionary or it's already filled with something?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]]` is not a list, but a string!

Before appending value to `groupPairsByKey['all']`, you need to make the value a list.

Your solution is already correct, it works perfectly in my case. Try to make sure that `groupPairsByKey` is a completely empty dictionary.

By the way, this is what i tried:

```
>>> words = "all/DT remaining/VBG all/NNS of/IN".split
>>> for word in words:
    wordPair = word.split('/')
    if wordPair[0] in groupPairsByKey:
        groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]].append(wordPair[1])
    else:
        groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]] = [wordPair[1]]


>>> groupPairsByKey
{'of': ['IN'], 'remaining': ['VBG'], 'all': ['DT', 'NNS']}
>>>
```

Also, if your code is formatted like the one you posted here, you'll get an indentationError.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks to me like you should be getting an IndentationError, if you are getting the message

> str object has no attribute append

then it means

```
groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]]
```

is a `str`, and `str`s do not have an append method.

---

The code you posted does not show how

```
groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]]
```

could have a `str` value. Perhaps put

```
if wordPair[0] in groupPairsByKey:
    if isinstance(groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]], basestring):
        print('{}: {}'.format(*wordPair))
        raise Hell
```

into your code to help track down the culprit.

---

You could also simplify your code by using a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
groupPairsByKey = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in fileIn:
    lineLength=len(line)
    words=line[0:lineLength-1].split(' ')
    for word in words:
        wordPair=word.split('/')
        groupPairsByKey[wordPair[0]].append(wordPair[1])
```

When you access a `defaultdict` with a missing key, the factory function -- in this case `list` -- is called and the returned value is used as the associated value in the `defaultdict`. Thus, a new key-value pair is automatically inserted into the `defaultdict` whenever it encounters a missing key. Since the default value is always a list, you won't run into the error
`str object has no attribute append` anymore -- unless you have 
code which *reassigns* an old key-value pair to have a new value which is a `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`my_dict["all"] = my_string.split('/')`

in Python,